# What does this method's return statement return?

Tags: c#

I saw a method written in C# that returns a boolean value.  The method's return statement looks like this:

```
return count > 0;
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it returns a value if count is greater than zero.  What happens if the value of 'count' is not greater than 0?  What gets returned?  Zero?  If that's the case, couldn't the return statement just say:

```
return count;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`false`, that trusty old constant representing the opposite of `true` will be returned if count is not greater than zero.

Answer (score 7):

It's returning the value of the expression `count > 0`. That's a Boolean expression (i.e. of type `bool`.)

It's like this:

```
bool result = (count > 0);
return result;
```

Another way of thinking of it (but *please* never write this code):

```
bool result = (count > 0) ? true : false;
return result;
```

or

```
bool result;
if (count > 0)
{
    result = true;
}
else
{
    result = false;
}
return result;
```

These are both ghastly contortions, but the important point is that `count > 0` is *just* an expression of type `bool`. Boolean expressions are *usually* used in conditions (if, while etc) but they're just ordinary expressions which can be evaluated like any other expression.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's an expression that returns a boolean value, so

```
return count > 0;
```

Returns true if count is 1+, false otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

you can rewrite the return statement like following :

```
if (count > 0)
            {return true;}
        else 
            {return false;}
```

if you return count, you would return an integer value, and the methods signature wouldn't match anymore

Comment: Very true, djerry.  That point of fact completely went over my head when I was looking at the return statement of the method.  I knew the value being returned was a bool, but I had never seen a return statement like that before (new to C# here) and it threw me off balance a bit, it seems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `count` is not greater than 0, it returns `false`.